# Dynamically add custom controls to a Google map and trigger events

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm working on a jQuery control that adds a Google map to a page.

So far so good.

As part of that, I'm adding some custom controls that allow me to place a single marker in a specific position (users home location, navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition); Again, so far so good.

In my custom controls, I've also got an address entry field that the user can type a search address in. If I get a single match, I can easily add the marker. If I get multiple results though, I want to add a set of links in the custom controls that the user can then click to choose from.

This is the problem. My code will render out the links just fine, but I'm not able to attach a DomListener to them.

This is the code that renders my links into a DIV in the custom control

```
if (results.length > 1 || results[0].partial_match) {
    $(element).data("addressResults", results);
    var html ="<div>Did you mean?<br /><ul>";
    for (var i=0; (i< results.length && i < 6); i++) {
        html+= '<li><a class"selectLocation" ' +
          'item="'+i+ '" >' + results[i].formatted_address+'</a></li>';
    }
    html+= '</ul></div>';
    html+= '<a class="closeAddressResults">None of these - Back to map</a>'
    resultsPanel // previously defined jQuery selector that works fine
        .html(html)
        .removeClass('error')
        .slideDown();
}
```

As I said, this renders things out OK and results in correctly placed links with the class 'selectLocation'

Normally, what I'd do is use a jQuery as $(document).on("click", ".selectLocation", function(e, data){...}); but that isn't possible.

As an alternative, what I was hoping to be able to do (that doesn't work) is create a dom listener as

```
var selectAddressCtrl = document.getElementByClassName('selectAddress');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(selectAddressCtrl, 'click', function(e) {...}
```

However, that doesn't seem to work anywhere.

the problem seems to be that the links are created Dynamically, where as Google only attaches events to items that already exist. I could keep bindign events, but I'm wary of creating multiple instances of it.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Dynamically bind on creation.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't required, but now I tried it, it works perfectly. Thank you, Andrew Peacock

Comment: I tried playing around with a few different ways, but binding on creation is the most simple and most likely to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew's comment is correct - the only way I've found to make this work is to create the UI elements the way Google documentation suggests and bind as they are added.

i.e.

```
foreach (linktoAdd)
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    (set link properties)
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(link, 'click', function(e) {...});
    (add element to UI)
}
```